# Trying to scrape the links on the page www.zath.co.uk using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website [www.zath.co.uk](http://www.zath.co.uk), and extract the links to all of the articles using Python 3. Looking at the raw html file I identified one of the sections I am interested in, displayed below using BeautifulSoup.

```
<article class="post-32595 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail category-games entry" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/CreativeWork">
       <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">
         <a class="entry-title-link" href="https://www.zath.co.uk/family-games-day-night-event-giffgaff/" rel="bookmark">
          A Family Games Night (&amp; Day) With giffgaff
         </a>
```

I then wrote this code to excute this, I started by setting up a list of urls from the website to scrape.

```
urlList = ["https://www.zath.co.uk/","https://www.zath.co.uk/page/2/",....."https://www.zath.co.uk/page/35/"
```

Then (after importing the necessary libraries) defined a function get all Zeth articles.

```
def getAllZathPosts(url,links):
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
    for a in soup.findAll('a'):
        url = a['href']
        c = a['class']
        if c == "entry-title-link":
            print(url)
            links.append(url)
    return
```

Then call the function.

```
links = []
zathPosts = {}

for url in urlList:
        zathPosts = getAllZathPosts(url,links)
```

The code runs with no errors but the links list remains empty with no urls printed as if the class never equals "entry-title-link". I have tried adding an else case.

```
else:
    print(url + " not article")
```

and all the links from the pages printed as expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: soup2 is not define, Correct it

Comment: thanks i have been changing cade back and forth trying to correct it and this was a mistype in the question..*sigh*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the below code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getAllZathPosts(url,links):
  response = requests.get(url).text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
  results = soup.select("a.entry-title-link")
  #for i in results:
    #print(i.text)
    #links.append(url)
  if len(results) >0:
    links.append(url)
  
links = []
urlList = ["https://www.zath.co.uk/","https://www.zath.co.uk/page/2/","https://www.zath.co.uk/page/35/"]
for url in urlList:
  getAllZathPosts(url,links) 
print(set(links))
```

Comment: The bit of code in hashed out worked great thanks. You just misunderstood i wanted to links.append(i) not url.

Comment: I already got that so I commented that code which will fit according to your requirement.

Comment: **correction** to elaborate on the misunderstanding i wanted to append the 'href' of the i that is being iterated over. Final Code: `def getAllZathPosts(url,links):
    response = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.select("a.entry-title-link")
    for i in results:
        print(i.text)
        links.append(i['href'])        
    #if len(results) >0:
        #links.append(results)
    return`

Comment: I have up voted it but as i am a stack overflow pleb it won't show XD.

Comment: Actually your question was not clear although I have shown you the path to solve. (:

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate it using range and extract article tag

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for page_no in range(35):
  page=requests.get("https://www.zath.co.uk/page/{}/".format(page_no))
  parser=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
  for article in parser.findAll('article'):
    print(article.h2.a['href'])
```

Comment: page wise is not in sequence and you miss `https://www.zath.co.uk` URL

Comment: websites take the first-page number as optional to display. 
[link](https://www.zath.co.uk/page/1/) `https://www.zath.co.uk/page/1/` and [link](https://www.zath.co.uk) `https://www.zath.co.uk` both will land on the same page, please try it out.